# Offset not contained in string & Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting an error when i am trying to pass the following code using wordpress's function.php. The error i am getting is

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  mb_strpos(): Offset not contained in string in /var/www/clients/client62/web322/web/wp-content/themes/ateo/functions.php on line 1063

Now for the code:

```
1059    <?php
1060             $img_id = getIdByGuid($images[0]);
1061             $img1_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'big_picture');
1062             ?>
1063             <img src="<?php echo $img1_url[0]; ?>" id="big_picture" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta( $img_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ) ?>" />
```

I want to make the error go away, but no luck searching google.

I also get the following error, but i am not sure if they are connected in some way:

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/clients/client62/web322/web/wp-includes/meta.php on line 808, referer: http://ateo.dk/wp-admin/post.php?post=5854&action=edit

The meta.php have not been changed at any time. Also, i found out that the memorylimit from our hostingprovider is 128mb, and they say this is very high. However i have seen other places that this may go as high as 512mb.

Comment: Are you sure you reference the right line in your code above? There's no mention of that function.

Comment: Try disabling all the active plugins and see if that helps with the memory error.

Comment: @rnevius Yes, i forgot to say that the specific line of code (line 1063) is `<img src="<?php echo $img1_url[0]; ?>" id="big_picture" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta( $img_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ) ?>" />`

Comment: That line is in *functions.php*?

Comment: Yes, the guy who made the site have put tons of own functions within the functions.php - this has worked fine for over a year, but now it suddently starts making errors.